# Dynamically adding an item to a toolbar in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, iphone, sencha-touch, extjs

i have a toolbar which is set up like so:

```
MyApp.Guide.channelbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
  items: [
    {
      text: 'loading...',
      ui: 'plain',
      disabled: true
    }
  ]
});
```

It displays on the screen as expected, and looks just fine. So later on, i make a JSONP request and in the callback, i try to remove the loading item and insert a segmented button like so:

```
MyApp.Guide.channelbar.items.add(
  new Ext.SegmentedButton({
    name: 'testseg',
    items: [{text:'test a'},{text:'test b'}]
  }));
```

Now i'm *certain* that callback is getting called, because in chrome's console i do the following to confirm that the item has been added:

```
MyApp.Guide.channelbar.items.items[1].name
```

But it just doesn't get updated on the screen. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you calling doLayout after adding the item?

Comment: Tried that, didn't make a difference. Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: Ok i tried it again, and it works now. Very strange, but thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

try using the your-class`the update method of the tab panel`,this will help you out
easily